# ASP.NET MVC truly log off with Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, logout

I have a logoff action on a controller as so:

```
    public ActionResult Logoff()
    {
        var x = Request.IsAuthenticated;
        var y = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Abandon();

        var a = Request.IsAuthenticated;
        var b = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        return View();
    }
```

However, x, y, a, and b, are all true. So when my view renders, it still behaves as if the user is logged in. Can someone please provide a solution and/or explanation?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` removes the authentication cookie, so you need to redirect after it instead of returning a view so that the client is notified:

```
public ActionResult Logoff()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Now in the `Index` action the user will no longer be authenticated.

Comment: Darin's right on. What I do at times is return a "return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);" That will send the user back to the login page you declare in the authentication area in your web.config. Same thing really...